# Problem with Angular component when initially loading Remote Data

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am playing around with the Kendo TreeView Control and i am running into the following issue. I created a reusable component which uses the kendo treeview and i pass the table which holds all the nodes as well as the array which holds all the selected keys guid's. when i pass the selected keys as a static array i dont get the error, if i tell it to get data from the backend api i get the folowing error

**ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'join' of null**

I am sure this has to do with the component trying to access the data which is not there yet. So not sure how i would have to tell the component to wait for it.

[StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-tree-remote-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally render the component when the data arrives with the `ngIf` directive.

```html
<app-kendo-tree
  *ngIf="selectedNodes$ | async as selectedNodes"
  [nodes]="data"
  [checkedKeys] = "selectedNodes"
  [checkBox] = true

></app-kendo-tree>
```

To conditionally wait for multiple requests, I'll suggest using [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest):

```js
vm$: Observable<{ data: any; selectedNodes: [] }>;

ngOnInit() {
    const data$ = this.getAllMenuItems();
    const selectedNodes$ = this.getAllSelectedNodes().pipe(shareReplay());
    this.vm$ = combineLatest([data$, selectedNodes$]).pipe(
      map(([data, selectedNodes]) => ({ data, selectedNodes }))
    );
  }
```

```html
<app-kendo-tree *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm"
  [nodes]="vm.data"
  [checkedKeys] = "vm.selectedNodes"
  [checkBox] = true

></app-kendo-tree>
```

Comment: That works, one more , how would i only render it if both data$ and selectedNodes have been returned ? 
<app-kendo-tree *ngIf="selectedNodes$ | async as selectedNodes"
  [nodes]="data$ | async"
  [checkedKeys] = "selectedNodes"
  [checkBox] = true
 
></app-kendo-tree>

Comment: Hard to follow in the comments, could you edit your question

Comment: Based on your sample we dont render the component until selectedNodes$ has returned data. I am wondering what the ngIf would be if i dont want to render until the data and the selectedNodes Observable have returned data. I updated the sample